# OSX Prevent mac updates to override config files

Tags: macos, mac, updates, macos-highsierra

I noticed that everytime I update my mac, the update overrides all my configuration files. For example, files such as `httpd.conf` in /etc/apache2 will be reset, and my old version will be renamed to `httpd.conf.pre-update` or `httpd.conf~previous`.

Is there a way to prevent this ? This breaks a lot of stuff on my mac...

Comment: Do you have the Server app installed? If so, do you really need it / can you do without it? I have a hunch this is more likely to happen on machines with Server than machines without.

Comment: No I do not have it